# how to store or fetch requests given by user to alexa voice service on raspberry pi in database?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service, avs

I am naive to alexa voice service.

I am trying to integrate machine learning algorithm(naive bayes) in alexa voice service sample app. To implement this algorithm i need to store all the request(voice commands given by user) which are successfully processed by amazon alexa into my local database which will be on raspberry pi with their time stamp and other information to process the data. 
How to do it?

Please give suggestions and provide on-line helpful resources.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform external API calls from the Alexa skill. So probably you need to set up API server on your Raspberry PI and send data to it. Or you can have separate API server and then fetch the data from it later.

There you can find examples of how to access external APIs https://github.com/alexa/alexa-cookbook/tree/master/external-calls/httpsGet

Comment: I have set up avs sample app on my raspberry pi. Can you provide a solution by which i can access my alexa recorded history in my custom skills or in my normal external code? I have searched a lot but i am unable to find how to get access to my history.

Comment: There is no way to access "recorded history". Alexa does not store it. She just says it back. After that, the "history" is lost. You can capture the text in the slot variables and use it for your needs.